# Is it only sha-1 that is supported as part of an object upload?

Tags: autodesk-forge

When uploading a file to a storage bucket, sha-1 is returned in the response. What about sha-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only SHA-1 is supported today. If you have a strong case for using other types of hashes, please let us know on `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we will pass the information to the engineering team.